# How do I pull out the first 3 lines of each ppm file?

Tags: python

All I have done is opened up the small file and appended the contents to a list called `files`. Files contains a list of the tiny ppm lines.

How do I remove the first three lines of this file from existence?

Here's an example of what a `.ppm` file looks like, it's called, tiny.ppm.

```
P3
5 5
255
255 0 0
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
255 0 0
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
255 0 0
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
255 0 0
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
100 150 175
255 0 0
```

My code is below, however, I want 'files' to eventually contain a list of 9 lists containing 9 different files' information, and remove the first three lines of all of those too.

```
def readFiles():
    files = []
    files.append(open('tiny.ppm','rU').readlines())
    print(files)
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the file and skip the first three lines:

```
def readFiles():
    files = []
    files.append(open('tiny.ppm','rU').readlines()[3:])
    print(files)
```

But you're more likely to end up with something like this to read multiple files:

```
def readFiles():
    from glob import glob
    files = []
    for f in glob('*.ppm'):
        content = open(f, 'rU').readlines()
        files.append(content[3:])
```

### edit

If you want all the files' pixel values mashed together into three colour channel lists:

```
r, g, b = [],[],[]
for filecontent in files:
    for line in filecontent:
        liner, lineg, lineb = line.split()
        r.append(liner)
        g.append(lineg)
        b.append(lineb)
```

(but then why did you keep them separate within 'files' ?)

### edit

ha ha, this is horrible

```
>>> r, g, b = [],[],[]
>>> [(r.append(pr),g.append(pg),b.append(pb)) for (pr,pg,pb) in [tuple(l.split()) for l in f for f in fs]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How would I then read the rest of the lines dropping the first number in a list called r, the second in a list called g, and the third in b? Because it's a list of lists, so the index of the first item in the list is the three values all together

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more robust for reading images and performing various operations on them, I recommend the Pillow package in Python.

```
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob

def readFiles():
    images = []
    for f in glob("*.ppm"):
        image = Image.open(f)
        image_pix = list(image.getdata())  # retrieve raw pixel values as a list
        images.append(image_pix)
    return images  # images is now a list of lists of pixel values
```

For example, you can crop an image:

```
box = (100, 100, 400, 400)
region = image.crop(box)
```

More examples and tutorial here: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html